# prevent jsTree from expanding the nodes after you select them programmatically

Tags: jstree

Is there a way to select a node without expanding nodes?  Every time I call the method to select a node, it will call the changed.jstree event and expand the nodes.  I want to select a node without expanding the nodes.

```
$('#jstree').jstree(true).select_node('info');


$('#jstree').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
               
});
```

UPDATE:

I also tried the below method to select a node and it still expanded the nodes:

```
 $('#jstree').jstree().select_node('info', false,true)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  You call the below method to check the default options and the boolean below to true to set the prevent_open.

```
$('#jstree').on('ready.jstree', function (e, data) {
data.instance.select_node(['info'], false, true);
});

 //$('#jstree').jstree().select_node('info', false,true)
```